# Problem with find and variables

Tags: bash

I have tried different variations of the following but nothing seems to work. Basically when `find` gets executed nothing appears to happen. Below I present my bash function code and my output when I run it.

I am interested in understanding what happens with the code below and why it
doesn't behave as when I type the command explicitly.

Also I got told I will not have access to `rgrep` in some boxes I will be working on and thus I try this approach for a generic solution to grepping for code etc.

```
function findin() {

if [ -z $1 ] ; then

    echo "Usage: findin <file pattern> <<grep arguments>>"
    return 1

fi

fIn[1]=$1

shift
fIn[2]="$@"

echo -- "${fIn[1]}"
echo -- "'${fIn[2]}'"

find -type f -name "'${fIn[1]}'" -print0 | xargs -0 grep --color=auto ${fIn[2]}
}
```

And the output is:

```
$ ls
Server.tcl  Server.tcl~  test.cfg  vimLearning.txt
$ find -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep --color=auto char
x      deletes char under cursor. NNx deletes NN chars to RHS of cursor.
r      type r and the next char you type will replace the char under the cursor.
$ findin '*.txt' char
-- *.txt
-- 'char'
```

Comment: Why are you using fIn[1] and fIn[2]?  What do you think that gives you that using properly named variables like `fn=$1;shift;pattern="$@"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern you probably intended to use was `*.txt`, but you are telling `find -name` to use `'*.txt'`, including the single quotes, which does not match any files.  The expansion works as follows:

**On the command line**, when you type

```
$ find -name '*.txt'
```

your shell sees `'*.txt'` is quoted, so it strips the quotes and passes the contents, `*.txt`, to `find`.

**In the function**,

```
find -name "'$var'"
```

the shell expands `$var` to `*.txt`.  Since the expansion occurred within double-quotes, the shell strips the double quotes and passes the contents, `'*.txt'`, to `find`.

The solution is simple: remove the single quotes in `find -name "'$var'"`.

---

I touched up your function for you:

```
findin () {
    if (( $# < 2 )); then
        >&2 echo "Usage: findin <file pattern> <grep arguments ...>"
        return 1    
    fi               
    pattern=$1               
    shift
    printf '%s\n' "-- ${pattern}"
    printf '%s ' "-- $@"
    echo
    find -type f -name "${pattern}" -print0 | 
            xargs -0 grep --color=auto "$@"
}
```

Comment: never mind previous comment if you saw it, I misread what you wrote.